# how to use a child mapper method which extends a parent mapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapper

I'm trying to call the child mapper method by a flexible case
But in this case, we don't know which method will be called even it extends parent mapper.  [spring boot framework with mybatis]

```
// ParentMapper
public interface ParentMapper
{
    // List<Map<String, String> findAll();
}

// Child1Mapper
public interface Child1Mapper extends ParentMapper
{
    List<Map<String, String> findAll();
}

// Child2Mapper
public interface Child2Mapper extends ParentMapper{
    List<Map<String, String> findAll();
}



@Autowired
Child1Mapper child1Mapper;

@Autowired
Child2Mapper child2Mapper;

// some class file
public ParentMapper getMapper(String param){
    switch(param){
        case "case1" : child1Mapper;
        case "case2" : child2Mapper;
        ... 10 more..
    }
}



public class example{
    public void somethid(){
        // this logic is in some biz
        ParentMapper mapper = getMapper("case1");  // <----`-` we do not know where `findAll method` located is in
        mapper.findAll();
    }
}
```

how to call the child mapper method

Answer (score 1):

Its clear in code if you pass `case1` to  `getMapper(String param)` method it will return `return new Child1Mapper()` child1mapper object, so if you invoke `findAll()` method then `child1mapper` class `findAll()` method will be invoked

In case if you pass `case2` then you will get `child2mapper` object `(which is like Parentmapper p = new Child2Mapper())` so if you call `findAll()` method `(p.findAll())` child2mapper `findAll()` method will be invoked

`child1mapper` and `child2maper` both are child classes of `parentmapper` but there is no relation ship between `child1mapper` and `child2mapper` so there is no concept of methods conflict

Comment: yes this is called `RunTime Polymorphism` which is parent reference having child object , check this https://www.javatpoint.com/runtime-polymorphism-in-java (check bank example)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have done is absolutely fine.

***Provided***: you are referring to actual implementation classes and not interfaces here

```
case "case1" : return new Child1Mapper();
case "case2" : return new Child2Mapper();
```

Interesting to know:
You just implemented a design pattern here.
Your `getMapper` method represents `Factory Method Pattern`. These type of methods are absolutely valid as per the need.

More information on `Factory Method Pattern`: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Comment: thank you for your information. Yes, your case we can use Factory method pattern then I can use finAll method but. this case ParentMapper interface doesn't have findAll method.

specifically, this code are working on spring boot framework with mybatis.

Comment: @김승갑 Its a basic object oriented feature. Interfaces are just definitions and your have your child classes who will provide the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You're missing the method signature in the `ParentMapper`

```
public interface ParentMapper
{
    List<Map<String, String>> findAll();
}
```

You'll need to specify the shared method signature for any classes that wants to implement the `ParentMapper` interface. The interface is the contract for the implementation.

This will obligate the Child1Mapper and Child2Mapper to supply the implementation details for that signature.

```
public interface ParentMapper
{
    List<Map<String, String>> findAll();
}

// Child1Mapper
public class Child1Mapper implements ParentMapper
{
    public List<Map<String, String>> findAll() { /* implementation */ }
}

// Child2Mapper
public class Child2Mapper implements ParentMapper{
    public List<Map<String, String>> findAll() { /* implementation */ }
}
```

`ParentMapper mapper = getMapper("child1"); mapper.findAll()` will use the `Child1Mapper` instance's implementation.

Considering that you are using Spring, you can adjust your factory method to return Spring Beans too. For example: (this will vary depending on how you wire your spring beans)

```
@Bean
Child1MapperBean() { return new Child1Mapper() }
@Bean
Child2MapperBean() { return new Child2Mapper() }

public ParentMapper getMapper(String param){
    switch(param){
       case "case1" : return Child1MapperBean();
       case "case2" : return Child2MapperBean();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out.... 
If ParentMapper, ChildMappers have same methods. it works well.

or we can think about reflection.. like this.

```
Mapper mapper = getMapperClass(name);
Method method = mapper.getClass().getMethod(mapperQueryId, Map.class);
return (List<Map<String, Object>>) method.invoke(mapper, params);
```